# Zookeeper goes OutOfMemory due to java heap space

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a service which depends on Zookeeper. However, I hit the OOM issue with Zookeeper and can see the below error :

```
ERROR  NIOServerCnxnFactory.java (line 44) Thread Thread[ProcessThread(sid:5 cport:-1):,5,main] died
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:135)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:197)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryOutputArchive.writeInt(BinaryOutputArchive.java:55)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.txn.SetDataTxn.serialize(SetDataTxn.java:59)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader.propose(Leader.java:754)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.ProposalRequestProcessor.processRequest(ProposalRequestProcessor.java:78)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor.pRequest(PrepRequestProcessor.java:673)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor.run(PrepRequestProcessor.java:131)
```

What does this error mean? Can someone elaborate?

What is the significance of this thread being dead?

I also see other errors like :

```
ERROR  NIOServerCnxnFactory.java (line 44) Thread LearnerHandler Socket[addr=/10.196.128.11,port=47073,localport=2888] tickOfNextAckDeadline:1544 synced?:true queuedPacketLength:0 died
ERROR  NIOServerCnxnFactory.java (line 44) Thread LearnerHandler Socket[addr=/10.196.128.13,port=59855,localport=2888] tickOfNextAckDeadline:1544 synced?:true queuedPacketLength:0 died
ERROR  NIOServerCnxnFactory.java (line 44) Thread Thread[RMI RenewClean-[10.196.128.14:7400],5,system] died
ERROR  NIOServerCnxnFactory.java (line 44) Thread Thread[RMI TCP Connection(idle),5,RMI Runtime] died
```

Can anyone explain what these error mean? And what happens when these threads are dead?

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper (or any other Java based process) shouldn't try to recover from java.lang.Error (like OOM), so basically you have nothing to do except restarting the JVM, but with more memory (google `Xmx zkServer`).

What is being used for? don't forget ZK is mainly for configuration: each znode can hold up to 1 MB of data, try to store in each znode the smallest possible serialized object.